# DBText to display data as multiple lines in Report Builder

Tags: delphi, subreport, reportbuilder

Please could someone help me with this.  I am using Report Builder for Delphi.  In my code I use multiple SQL queries in my dataset.  In Report Builder I have DBText component which refers to my SQL queries. When I run my SQL queries in IBExpert I get the correct result but when I put it into Delphi code and setup the report, it does not do what I want it to do.

What must happen is that it must show on the report data line by line for the sales of different stores. EG: Store one and the value
            Store two and the value   etc..

Could some advise me please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your are using ReportBuilder by Digital Metaphors.

You need to place your DBText components in a subreport and link this subreport to your pipeline. This way, the report knows to iterate through your pipeline and for each row in your dataset to print a line as defined in your subreport.

Digital Metaphors has quite a good wiki for all kinds of tutorials. See  http://www.digital-metaphors.com:8080/index.php?title=Data_Access/Fundamentals/Data_Traversal&highlight=subreport for an explanation of data traversal within reports.